# Relationship between Th1 and Th2 and their cross-regulation (+ understanding what cross-regulation means)

Tags: virus, immune-system, terminology

Apologies, biology is not my area of expertise but I do have an interest in it.

I "know" that Th1 and Th2 cross-regulate but I'm not sure what that means... Could it mean that if one decreases, the other must increase to maintain some baseline or am I completely off track?

If there is, is there any way to "balance" the two? Apologies, I did quite a bit of Googling but it seems like I'd need to know far more about the topic of immunology to understand the answers I'm reading online.

Comment: The situation is very more complex than your question suggests. This recent review, although focusing on relevance to tumor immunotherapy, should get you started with fairly recent knowledge: "Differentiation and Regulation of T H Cells: A Balancing Act for Cancer Immunotherapy"  PMID: 34012451 PMCID: PMC8126720 DOI: 10.3389/fimmu.2021.669474

Comment: Ahh, that's unfortunate. So, it's not the case that a change in one causes an increase/ decrease in the other then. Thanks for the resource! I guess I have a lot of prior reading to do

Comment: The immune system is generally acknowledged as being the 2nd most complex system in the body, after only the nervous system.  The history of the study of immune system cells has tended to be a new cell classification scheme driven by experimental results, followed by more experimental results and further sub-classification, and so forth.

Comment: Gotcha. thank you so much for the resources and insight. Do you feel that it is possible to read that paper or to gain insight into this without having an advanced biology / immunology degree? All I've got is pre-college biology

Comment: My strategy is just to take a look at a paper's abstract and introduction. If there are many terms/concepts I don't understand and which are not explained in the introduction, then I look for background material to understand those. In general, I would recommend the latest 9th edition of Janeway's Immunobiology if you have enough interest to spend $80 on learning about the subject.